# IE8 forced to compatibility mode

Tags: internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

My team is developing a website with a pretty complicated UI; jQuery, ASP.Net AJAX, etc.  Of course I want my site to be compatible with all the modern browsers.  Sometimes, in testing or general usage of the site while it is being developed, IE8 tells me that the page doesn't work in standards mode and it is switching to compatibility mode but it never tells me why.  Is there some log or report or setting or something in IE8 that I can use to find out what upset IE8 Standards mode? Everything seems to work fine in FF, Chrome, Safari, and IE7 so what is it that IE8 doesn't like and how can I find that out?

Comment: +1 for trying your best to work toward standards rather than just getting IE to do what you want.

Comment: What is the exact error message? There are a couple of cases where this happens for different reasons... worst is when the IE8 renderer crashes(!) and it decides to try again in IE7; debugging IE in this case is difficult.

Comment: Turns out the problems were coming from the virus scanner my company uses: Sophos.  The BHO has some conflicts with IE8 which was causing IE to fall back to IE7 mode.  We found some posts in the Sophos forums that didn't offer much help.  We disabled the BHO and every thing is cool now.

Answer (score 2):

The issue has to do with the styles that you are using which IE8 layout engine has trouble interpreting. Unfortunately there is no comprehensive list of style combinations what will trigger this behavior. You have the ability to turn off the automatic recovery on your own machine by going to 'Tools->Internet Options-> Advanced Tab -> Browsing -> and uncheck 'Automatically recovery from layout errors ..."

This is of course only applied to your machine and is of no benefit to your customers if the layout error is triggered. I do not have an answer to your specific issue, but I'd suggest validating your css against the W3C CSS validator:
http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Any try removing complex styles one at a time until you find the combination that is triggering the error for your site.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not an actual answer, but FWIW if it's complaining about the page as delivered (e.g., before you manipulate it with the DOM), you should be able to find out what it's complaining about if you pass that same page through the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org).  Of course, the validator checks against the validator's interpretation of the standards (which is very good though possibly not perfect) rather than *Microsoft's* interpretation of standards (no comment), so the two may not always align...

Answer (score 1):

I suppose there are several issues that could cause IE8 to change into Compatibility  Mode, but the style that I found in my site was using a pseudo element on the body tag. Removing this stopped IE8 from automatically switching to Compatibility Mode.

Removed this:

```
body:after {
    // This causes IE8 to freak out and change into Compatibility Mode!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check at [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/compatibility.html) to see if they know of obvious causes.